# Jest / Enzyme not properly simulating my component method?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have an input and when the "enter" key is pressed, using "onKeyPress" I want to set some state. What it does is update the languages array on the state by adding in the new input value.

The functionality works, but the test fails. Here is my code.

This is the function that gets called when "onKeyPress" gets called.

```
  onLanguagesChange = e => {
    if (e.charCode === 13 && this.state.languageEntry) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const language = this.state.languageEntry;
      const languages = [...this.state.languages, language];
      this.setState(() => ({ languages, languageEntry: '' }));
    }
  };
```

This is the test

```
test('it should set languages when enter key is pressed on languages input', () => {
  const value = 13;
  const wrapper = shallow(<Form />);
  wrapper.setState({ languageEntry: 'Python' });
  wrapper.setState({ languages: ['JavaScript'] });
  wrapper
    .find('input')
    .at(1)
    .simulate('keydown', {
      charCode: { value }
    });
  expect(wrapper.state('languages')).toBe(['JavaScript', 'Python']);
});
```

This is the input inside the component. The onChange method just sets the text input on the languageEntry prop on state.
The method that is called from onKeyPress is what grabs the languageEntry value and updates the languages array on the state.

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="text-input"
  value={this.state.languageEntry}
  onKeyPress={this.onLanguagesChange}
  placeholder="Programming languages"
  onChange={this.onLanguageChange}
/>
```

And here is a screenshot of the failing test.

[image: Failing test]

Comment: Can you be sure that the input being found by the test is the right one?  Perhaps a better selector (using .text-input) or a name would be better?

Comment: I just tried adding its own unique className and using that instead. Still same failing test.

Comment: I don't think you need to wrap `value` in curly braces. By doing that, your passing an object instead of an int value

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mount` and not `shallow` for [simulate](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html) to work

```
 const wrapper = mount(<Form />);
```

Since you are listening to `onKeyPress` in your component, why not simulate a `keypress` event as well:

```
 wrapper
    .find('input')
    .at(1)
    .simulate('keypress', {
      charCode: { value }
    });
```

Comment: Changed it to mount as well as simulated keypress. Still failed. This is very odd.

Comment: Are you able to debug it to see what's going on. Also why are you using `this.setState(() => ({ languages, languageEntry: '' }));` instead of `this.setState({ languages, languageEntry: '' });`

Comment: Apparently using a function to return the new state is a practice that is becoming standard in the react community. I'm not sure exactly why but been seeing it used alot now.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the curly braces from `value`

```
test('it should set languages when enter key is pressed on languages input', () => {
  const value = 13;
  const wrapper = shallow(<Form />);
  wrapper.setState({ languageEntry: 'Python' });
  wrapper.setState({ languages: ['JavaScript'] });
  wrapper
    .find('input')
    .at(1)
    .simulate('keydown', {
      charCode: value
    });
  expect(wrapper.state('languages')).toBe(['JavaScript', 'Python']);
});
```

By wrapping it in curly braces, you're creating an enhanced object literal that'll look like `{value: 13}` instead of just `13`

Comment: Tried without curly, still no luck. hmmm